# Sdl Web 8 CD installation issue

Tags: dxa, web8, sdl-tridion

I am getting error while trying to update discovery service with its capability using java discovery registration tool. First time I run the updated it was fine ,then I have configured deployer,session content,preview and again tried to run the tool .but this time I am getting error "unable to make POST request to oData service for http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc" URL and service query "/ContentServiceCapabilities"is not allowed.

I think this is permission issue but not able to figure out . I am using "cmuser" account for configRepository ClientId and using port 8083 for content service capabilities.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I got the issue , it should be registration user instead of cmuser.